# What's the difference between getting the High Road or Low Road during the Marla mission?

Tags: rebel-galaxy-outlaw

I decided to stick with my old time friend Marla, but I would like to know what would happen to the story-line if I sided with the two jacks.

Would the story-line change or just a faction points up and down?